# Object image recognition - API

Tags: image-processing

My goal is to setup a service based on static image input and detect presence of a series of object based on other subset of images.
OpenCV probably can do so, just wondering if there’s some other way using cloud API or other services . Thank you

Comment: You might want to check out the [Ciliar API](https://ciliar.co). (disclaimer I run it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two Image recognition APIs that I've used that should work for you:

- [Imagga](https://imagga.com/)
- [ImageRecognition API](http://imagerecognition.apixml.net/)